# SQL / PHP If equals NULL show else

Tags: php, sql

I've been working on this all day, I'm trying to do a simple SQL check, I have two fields with activation codes, If the user has already activated the account the second field has the activation code entered from the first field and if the user isn't activated the second field simply says NULL.

I'm trying to put together a quick snippet to check if user is activated simply by checking if it says NULL.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        <?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$activation_code = $_POST['activation_code'];
$activation_codeurl = $activation_code;
$usernameurl = $username;

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "aardvark";
$db_use = "aardvark";
$db_pass = "aardvark";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_use, $db_pass);
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

$checkcustomer = mysql_query("SELECT `Check_Activation` FROM `members` WHERE `Username` = '".$username."' & `Activation` = '".$activation_code."'; ");
$rows_found = mysql_num_rows($checkcustomer);

if ($rows_found > 0) {  

    // If unactivated value should be NULL allowing the user to follow through to the forms, If Value is anything else this means the user is activated and should not have access to the forms.
    $val = mysql_query($checkcustomer);
    if ($val == 'NULL') 
        {
            // Redirect User to either form 1,2,3 depending on first number of Username

            $username = substr($username, 0, 1);
            if($username == '1') { 
                $redirect_url='form-one.php?membernumber='.$usernameurl.'&activation_code='.$activation_codeurl;
            } elseif($username == '2') { 
                $redirect_url='form-two.php?membernumber='.$usernameurl.'&activation_code='.$activation_codeurl;              
            } elseif($username == '3') { 
                $redirect_url='form-three.php?membernumber='.$usernameurl.'&activation_code='.$activation_codeurl;
            }
            header("Location:". $redirect_url);
    } 
}

else 

{
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=960, initial-scale=0.32">
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://welovebarrio.com/favicon.gif">
        <link rel="icon" href="http://welovebarrio.com/favicon.gif" type="image/gif">
        <title>Friends of BARRIO</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35015193-1']);
                    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'welovebarrio.com']);
                    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
                    (function() {
                        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                    })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="inner-wrapper stage-one">
            <div class="barrio-logo">Friends of Barrio</div>
            <div class="barrio-wel-message">
                <h1>Welcome Friends of Barrio</h1>
                <span>-</span>
                <h2>Enter a valid membership number<br/> and activation code to continue</h2>
            </div>
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="check-activation.php" class="membership-form">
                <h3>Your membership number</h3>
                <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" class="membership-number">

                <h3>our activation code</h3>
                <input name="activation_code" type="text" id="activation_code" value="<?php echo $activation_code; ?>" class="activation-code">

                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Continue" class="membership-continue">
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="error-message">
            <span>Your membership number &amp; activation code <br/>is not valid, please check and re-enter</span>
        </div>


    <div class="background-tl"></div>
    <div class="background-tr"></div> 
    <div class="background-bl"></div>
    <div class="background-br"></div> 
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
$con->close();
?>
```

[image: Database]
[image: Activation]
[image: Form Redirect]

Comment: use if($val == "NULL"), using just one = you're assigning a value to your $val variable, not checking if it is NULL or not

Comment: Just a couple of friendly tips: 1) I hope those are dummy passwords, 2) mysql_[connect|select_db|query] is generally viewed as an insecure way of connecting and querying in PHP. Try to switch to either mysqli or PDO, as they are much better.

Comment: Thank you Raad for the above and no these are dummy details, I have though about a recode but I'm looking for a quick solution and quick!

Comment: I can't see where you get `$username` and `$activation_codeurl` from? Also, I assume `Check_Activation` is the "second" field, but which is the "first"?

Comment: I've added an image to explain a little better.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see you supplying a value for `$activation_code`, which means the query will never return a result. Are you providing a value somewhere?

Comment: Raad, I've uploaded the full code and screen shots.

Comment: ok - screenshots not actually needed, just code, but cool anyway. Try to put all the relevant code in from the start, otherwise you end up playing a game of Q&A tennis! =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46857/discussion-between-adam-wadsworth-and-raad)

Comment: You need to use `is_null` in your latest code. I have updated my answer to include this, so give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so when you issue a query and return a column that could be null, the correct way to check that is by using [is_null](https://www.php.net/is_null)

Your code needs to be something like:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$activation_code = $_POST['activation_code'];
$activation_codeurl = $activation_code;
$usernameurl = $username;

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "aardvark";
$db_use = "aardvark";
$db_pass = "aardvark";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", $db_use, $db_pass);

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

$checkcustomer = mysql_query("SELECT `Check_Activation` FROM `members` WHERE `Username` = '".$username."' & `Activation` = '".$activation_code."'; ");
$rows_found = mysql_num_rows($checkcustomer);

if ($rows_found > 0) {
  // If unactivated value should be NULL allowing the user to follow through to the forms, If Value is anything else this means the user is activated and should not have access to the forms.
  $val = mysql_query($checkcustomer);
  
  if (is_null($val)) {
    // Redirect User to either form 1,2,3 depending on first number of Username
    $username = substr($username, 0, 1);
    
    if($username == '1') {
      $redirect_url='form-one.php?membernumber='.$usernameurl.'&activation_code='.$activation_codeurl;
    } elseif($username == '2') {
      $redirect_url='form-two.php?membernumber='.$usernameurl.'&activation_code='.$activation_codeurl;
    } elseif($username == '3') {
      $redirect_url='form-three.php?membernumber='.$usernameurl.'&activation_code='.$activation_codeurl;
    }
    
    header("Location:". $redirect_url);
  }
} else {
...
}
?>
```